Upcoming moderator election
We wanted you to know that since the workload vs. possible activity for the current moderators reached critical levels, there will be elections for one (probably, possibly more) new moderator(s), starting with the first phase on August 13th.
Feel free to share your thoughts and start to think about whether you'd like to join the moderation team for some fresh wind and building a better community experience ❤️
What is a moderator and what can they do that others cannot?
A moderator is, in essence, still a fellow community member, albeit not a "simple" one. Compared to achieving 5,000 rep points, the main differences are that your open/close and (un)deletion votes become binding and you can suspend accounts with some tools to help you decide whether this is justified in the first place.
Aside from that, the help center page provides most relevant information, including the moderator agreement we need to accept and abide by.
What do we expect from new, fellow moderators?
First of all, help with the flags cough. Of course, knowing or learning how StackExchange arised and the history of the community trying to bring the SE model and the subject of philosophy in some way together will help. New input and energy for shaping and developing a proper community would be most welcome, since any attempt to form something more than individuals debating issues to death in comment threads failed so far. Generally, nobody is born a moderator, so no shame in asking. There are places for that only other mods can find, see, and enter.

The potential workload for you moderators looks to be large -- I have always wondered how you get by with only 3 of you!

@JD I encourage you to apply for the moderator position.

@Coniforld  I encourage you to apply for the moderator position.

@Jo Wheler -- I encourage you to apply for the moderator position

@Kristian Berry -- I encourage you to apply for the moderator position.

@causitive -- I encourage you to apply for the moderator position

Herr Klöcking, for a better community experience, it might help to describe the rights and responsibilities of a moderator, as well as the expectations by the corporate overlords and fellow moderators. Part of the challenges of building a culture around this site is the anonymity and statelessness of communications and a mixture of beliefs about best practices, not just in participation by non-moderators but also by moderators themselves. Your thoughts on the realities of the current state of contributions of both groups might go some way to outlining a vision of where the site is headed. Without that sort of collective vision, and cooperation geared to bring about world-to-mind fit, it might appear that a sort of anarchy looms discouraging earnest and capable contributors.

added what you asked for, I hope. As of particular visions, I will not offer those, since I would find it problematic to limit any new moderator in their input.

@PhilipKlöcking Your contributions are appreciated, as always.

There's lots of qualified candidates, but I'm nominating J D.
Generally positive, enthusiastic, supportive and welcoming to the other users; has extremely broad knowledge (which for a mod can be better than deep) heavily focusing on academic citations; is generally one of the most active users not only in terms of answering questions but also making edits to questions, re-tagging them, etc.; is also one of the most upvoted contributors to the site; shows an independent sense of principle regarding what the site should be like implying personal concern for site quality.

I'll take the downvote as Philip's disapproval. ; )

Oh, and thanks for kind words. I'm a bit of an imp at heart so it's nice to have someone use kind words. :D

I second this nomination.  JD puts a lot of thought and effort into trying to improve this community, and seeks to make PhilSE a more welcoming/open place.
